# How can I limit transfer speed?

Tags: java, android, networking, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm writing an FTP (client) service for Android, that is intended to upload video contents in background.

I was thinking that users may get bothered if my service fills the whole connection band.

What is the simplest way to **dinamically set an (upload) speed limit** for my service? Is there any Android workaround, shall I use some commons-net feature, or shall I calculate tranfers rate by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd calculate the transfer rates by hand. The devices which can limit transfer bandwidth consumption in this scenario are going to be located between the client and the server (layer 3 devices like routers), or the server, or the client themselves.

Since all you are guaranteed have control over is the client, you'll need to do it yourself. I don't know of any libraries which will handle this for you.  The calculation should be pretty simple. Just bytes transferred over time right?

Also I suggest having a selection in your FTP app for users which can throttle the bandwidth your FTP app is using.